# check if there is any of the chars inside the textbox

Tags: c#, string, winforms

I have a chararray on global, button and textbox, how do I check if the word in textBox1.Text contains the letters in the chararray?

```
char[] letters = { 'a', 'e' };

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool containsAnyLetter = textBox1.Text.IndexOfAny(letters) >= 0;

    if (containsAnyLetter == true)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("your word contains a or e");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this to see if the string contains any of the letters:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool containsAnyLetter = letters.Any(c => textBox1.Text.Contains(c));
}
```

Or more simply:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool containsAnyLetter = textBox1.Text.IndexOfAny(letters) >= 0;
}
```

Comment: And if you need it to contain all the letters in the array you can use "All" instead of "Any".

Comment: Error 1 A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'WindowsFormsApplication4.Form1.letters' C:\Users\bilgisayar\Desktop\WindowsFormsApplication4\WindowsFormsApplication4\Form1.cs 22 34 WindowsFormsApplication4

Comment: @HakanErbaslar You'll have to write that code *inside* of your method. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `String.IndexOfAny(char[] anyOf)` method ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/11w09h50.aspx)):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox1.Text.IndexOfAny(letters) >= 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Your word contains a or e.");
    }
}
```

Also, keep in mind that **IndexOfAny is case-sensitive** (`a` will not match `A`).

If you want to create a case-insensitive method, you could create an extension method:

```
public static class StringIndexExtensions
{
    public static bool CaseSensitiveContainsAny(this char[] matchChars, string textToCheck)
    {
        return matchChars.Any(c => textToCheck.IndexOf(
            c.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
            StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0);
    }
}
```

Then you could do the following:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (letters.CaseSensitiveContainsAny(textBox1.Text))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Your word contains a or e.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Regex`

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Regex.IsMatch(textBox1.Text, @"(a|e)"))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("your word contains a or e");
            }
        }
```